# How to prevent Curl upload to presigned Url S3

Tags: amazon-s3, curl

I'm using Presigned URL S3 to secure two secret keys on the server side, but I'm having the problem that anyone else with a valid pre Url will use curl to upload a malicious bucket file and apparently ruining everything, is there a way to prevent this
[Curl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSRSg.png)
In the picture above, I signed the link with the content Type of ms word but Curl can upload the .exe file from another computer

no solution yet, no solution yet

Comment: Only share the signed URL to the intended recipient, share it securely over an encrypted channel, tell the recipient not to share it or re-use it for other purposes, and specify a short expiration.

Comment: You're very much focusing on the wrong problem.  Even if you find some way to block curl specifically, any number of other clients could have been used, including a plain browser, to perform an upload of malicious content.  You should assume all content is malicious and act accordingly.